# Show that there exists some $g(y/x) = \frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given: $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$

Show that there exists some $g(y/x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$

---

Is my way of doing this problem correct?

---

FIRST: Solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$ yields: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$

SECOND: Let $v(y/x) = \frac{y}{x}$

-->$y=v(y/x)x$

-->$\frac{dy}{dx} = v^{'}(y/x)*\frac{-y}{x^{2}}*x + v(y/x)$

-->$\frac{dy}{dx} = v(y/x) - \frac{y}{x}*v^{'}(y/x)$

THIRD: Therefore, $\frac{dy}{dx} = g(y/x) = v(y/x) - \frac{y}{x}*v^{'}(y/x)=\frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}$

-->$g(y/x) = v(y/x) - \frac{y}{x}*v^{'}(y/x)$

Comment: Can we solve _every_ differential equation of the first order?

Comment: As long as they are separable, homogeneous, exact or linear I think we can. I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Is your problem right? I mean assume $ydx+\cos xdy=0$, what's $g$ in your solution, for instance?

Comment: It would be $g(y/x)=\frac{-y}{cosx}*\frac{1/x}{1/x} = \frac{-y/x}{\frac{cosx}{x}}$

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHH NVM GOT IT. I CANT USE THIS METHOD FOR ALL FIRST ORDER D.E.